# Why do I have to initialize "j"?

Tags: java, initialization, nested-loops

Here is an example code from [docs.oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
        { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
        { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
        { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
    };
    int searchfor = 12;

    int i;
    int j = 0;
    boolean foundIt = false;

search:
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
             j++) {
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                foundIt = true;
                break search;
            }
        }
    }

    if (foundIt) {
        System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);
    } else {
        System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
    }
}}
```

and here is my question: Why do I have to initialize the variable j before the nested for loops are executed? When I don't do, the code is compiled with an error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize `j` because the compiler doesn't know if it will get initialized in the inner `for` loop before it's accessed in the final `if` statement.

As far as the compiler is concerned, the body of the outer `for` loop might not be executed.

Comment: Theoretically the compiler could know the value of `arrayOfInts.length` and determine that the initializer for the inner `for` loop is going to be hit (the info is there).  In practice, it is just not that smart.

Comment: That's absolutely true. What confused me is that there is not the same need for the variable i. However, I have just realized that since the variable i is used in the first loop, it will be definitely initialized. Thanks.

Comment: Right - specifically, i is initialized in the *initialization* of the first loop, which is guaranteed to be attempted if the for statement is reached.

Answer (score 2):

If `arrayOfInts.length` is 0, `j` will not be initialised. For the compiler to determine that `j` will always be initialised, you would need the condition of the first loop to be a constant expression. For example, if you replace the outer loop with:

```
for (i = 0; true; i++)
```

the compiler will accept `int j;` without initialisation.

The detailed rules are defined in the [JLS #16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html). In particular, `j` needs to be definitely assigned before it is used in your print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `j` outside of the for loop.

In particular, you are using it in the print statement you have at the bottom of your code.